# EJB + Webservice error on build process

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm a java beginner. I had use netbean for create project Java EE>Enterprise Application and create Entity Class from Database and create JPA Persistance (I'm not sure to call this). So when I create ejb already done. I will use call ejb by web service. This my problem when I use web service with out ejb class or call ejb . It can build and deploy application but when I use ejb. I got error from bulid application. Anyone can explain me for slove this problem.

**This error build process**

```
Deploying D:\Project\Source\Dev\PYS\PYSServices\PYSServices-war\dist\PYSServices-war.war
{"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"PYSServices-war.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"PYSServices-war.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"PYSServices-war.war\""}}}}
D:\Project\Source\Dev\PYS\PYSServices\PYSServices-war\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1052: The module has not been deployed.
```

**This server log**

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."PYSServices.ear"."PYSServices-ejb.jar".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."PYSServices.ear"."PYSServices-ejb.jar".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment "PYSServices-ejb.jar" of deployment "PYSServices.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.getRequiredService(ServiceContainerImpl.java:447) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.getDefaultResourceAdapterName(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:273)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processMessageBeans(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:153)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processAnnotations(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.processAnnotations(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

This is my web service source code. My probelm it will happen when I type annotation @EJB. It can't compile and building to war file. If I not to use EJB it can building and deploy to jboss server success.

public class PysWebServices {

```
@Resource
WebServiceContext wsContext;

@EJB
private PysUserFacade pysUserFacade;

@WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
    return "Hello " + txt + " !";
}

private boolean userValidate(String userid,String password, String email, String mobileno){
    boolean rev = true;

    if (userid != null && password != null && email != null && mobileno != null) { 

        if (userid.length() <5){ rev = false;}
        if (password.length() < 6) { rev= false;}
        if (!email.contains("@")) { rev = false;}
        if (mobileno.length() != 10) {rev = false; }

    } else {
        rev = false;
    }

    return rev;
}

@WebMethod(operationName="Create User")
public String crateUser(@WebParam(name="userId") String userid,@WebParam(name="userPassword") String password, @WebParam(name="eMail") String email, @WebParam(name="mobileNo") String mobileNo){
    String rev="";

    MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
    String clientIP = req.getRemoteAddr();

    if (userValidate(userid, password, email, mobileNo)){
        PysUser eUser = new PysUser();
        eUser.setUserId(userid);
        eUser.setUserPassword(password);
        eUser.setMobileNo(mobileNo);
        eUser.setCreateIp(clientIP);
        eUser.setCreateDtm(new Date());
        pysUserFacade.create(eUser);
        rev = "Create User Success";
    } else {
        rev = "Err001:Verify Create User Faile";
    }

    return rev;
}
```

}

Comment: you should post your code to help others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

didn't get exactly your problem, but looking at the error message i guess:

You might need to activate/enable EJB specification in your project.
Make sure you included all required annotations in your ejbs

Hope this helps

Comment: Check if you didn't forget the annotation @WebService before class declaration, otherwise, try to separate your business logic and your web services, 
manage your JPA entities using session beans and 
use your session beans in the web service class